# How to render multiple React components through a single index.js file correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created two React component classes, one creates a counter and the other one creates a simple string wrapped in HTML tags. I'm trying to render both of them through my index.js to a HTML file, the counter works but the string does not and I need help understanding why. (I've been through multiple tutorials but can't seem to find one that would help me understand the issue).

Here is my counter class (which I am able to render in the HTML file):

```
import React from 'react';

class Counter extends React.Component{   constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
    };   }

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
        }}
      >
        Count: {this.state.count}
      </button>
    );   } } export default Counter;
```

The string class (that I can't render in the HTML):

```
import React from 'react';

export class Exactum extends React.Component{

  render() {
    return (
      <p>this is exactum</p>
    );   } }

export default Exactum;
```

And the index.js file I'm using to render them:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Counter from './components/Counter';
import Exactum from './components/Exactum';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Counter),
    document.getElementById('mount')
  );
});

ReactDOM.render(<Exactum />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here is the HTML file I'm using:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Counter</title>
  <script src="/bundle.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <p>Counter</p>
    <div id="mount"></div>
    <p>Exactum should appear here:</p>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I ask why you’re mixing and matching JSX and JavaScript?

Comment: Can you point out where I am doing this in a way I shouldn't? (Sorry, still very new to JS and JSX in general, followed a tutorial to get the counter component made and rendered)

Comment: It’s fine, just confusing. React should be able to have 2 mounting points. Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Not seeing any errors, seems to be compiling without problems

Comment: Why are you not waiting for `DOMContentLoaded` with the second mount as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bundle.js is in the Head of your application instead of the end of your Body tag.

Why inside the index.js the `<Counter />` Works and not the `<Exactum />` ?

it's because you add the event ***DOMContentLoaded*** to Counter so, when the JavaScript is loaded in the Head of the HTML, **the event is not triggered because the DOM is not loaded**, but the ReactDOM try to render Exactum in the DOM and fails.

But when the DOM is fully Loaded the event ***DOMContentLoaded*** is triggered and ReactDOM can render Counter in the DOM because the DOM is now Loaded.

Try this and tell me if it works: put the bundle.js at the end of the `<body>` tag.

Comment: This seems to have solved the problem, thank you very much!